# Discord.py missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try to run the command I always get this error message: TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
    with open('channel.json', 'r') as f:
        jchannel = json.load(f)

    channel = jchannel[str(ctx.guild.id)]

    await channel.send(f"Welcome!")
```

**Full error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\NexaHn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Comment: `on_ready` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: This is only a test because it is basically specified as "on member join".

Comment: But otherwise, how could it be solved?

Comment: If you delete `ctx` as the argument it will work.

Comment: But it also says that `ctx` is not defined, But I use `ctx` to get the server id.
(NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined)

Comment: It's not possible to get the guild ID on the `on_ready` event unless it's hardcoded, [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready) takes **0** arguments. Please read the docs, it can't be more clear

Comment: All right, I'll look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation you could see that *on_ready* does not take any arguments. It's not possible to pass in ctx.

Also, what are you trying to do? A welcome command? There is a function called on_member_join, look into that if you are trying to do what I think you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you still haven't checked the docs, here is a link to take a quick look at it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join

Comment: It would be to send a welcome message to a specific channel that you would retrieve from the json file.

Comment: I really want to know that for a given event, that I can recall json file information.

Comment: Was that a question you've asked? Because everytime the user joins you can actually retrieve the channel that is saved in a json file.